# Null coalescing operator in if-condition

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic, null-coalescing-operator

I'm being confused as to how the null coalescing operator in PHP works and I'd like some explanation for the following if possible:

I have an associative array representing data posted to the server. One of the values in that array can either be a boolean or just simply not set. I'm using that value in an if-condition that checks for that value being present & set to `true` and one other condition. The way I do the checking for the value being present is that I use the null coalescing (`??`) operator to replace the missing value with `false`.

This seems to change the result of the if-condition. As long as the condition is present, the if condition returns `true`, regardless of the second part of my if condition.

How is this possible?

```
<?php

$body = [];
$body['variable'] = true;
if ($body['variable'] ?? false && false) {
    echo('true');
} else {
    echo('false');
}

// true

unset($body['variable']);
if ($body['variable'] ?? false && false) {
    echo('true');
} else {
    echo('false');
}

// false
```

Comment: Can you add brackets to get clear of precedence problems?

Comment: `&&` has higher precedence than `??`, so it's equivalent to `if ($body['variable'] ?? (false && false))`

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Why not just check for true?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just `$body['variable'] ??= false` before your condition; if it's null/unset, set it to false.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot for that explanation! That answered my question perfectly and also helped me understand the page of documentation you linked me!